# how to create search box to filter data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, search

first of all I'm using this site as a template for what I'm trying to do except im adding a search box on top of this: http://www.dougv.com/demo/jquery_sort_records/js.php (due to reference blocking you should copy and paste the link to view it. else you will run into a 403 forbidden error)

I want to create a simple search box that will search upon a certain attribute and display any results found (basically a filter). Here's what I have so far as part of the code.
so far the table appears well however I want to add a search box that will search upon the first name attribute.

any help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#sortedtable").tablesorter({ sortlist: [0,0] });
            });
        </script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
            if(!$link = mysql_connect("database_server", "user_name", "password")) {
                echo "Cannot connect to db server";
            }
            elseif(!mysql_select_db("database_name")) {
                echo "Cannot select database";
            }
            else {
                if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table")) {
                    echo "Cannot parse query";
                }
                elseif(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
                    echo "No records found";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<table id=\"sortedtable\" class=\"bordered\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
                    echo "<thead>\n<tr>";
                    echo "<th>Record ID</th>";
                    echo "<th>First Name</th>";
                    echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
                    echo "<th>Birthday</th>";
                    echo "<th>Department</th>";
                    echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n";
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
                        echo "<tr><td>$row[person_id]</td><td>$row[person_name]</td><td>$row[person_surname]</td><td>$row[person_birthdate]</td><td>$row[person_department]</td></tr>\n";
                    }
                    echo "</table><br />\n";
                }
            }
?>

<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="js.php">
<font face="Calibri"> </font>
Search: <input type="text" name="search_b" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search for your term..."> </input>
</form>
```

Comment: 403: Forbidden error at the link

Comment: @ITroubs i know but it still works, for some reason it only works when you paste the url in manually

Comment: Then you have some kind of reference blocker

Comment: @ITroubs its not my site, its simply a page of the code all up and running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i would advise you to enclose array acces in strings like this: `" some tring {$array['key']} " thus you won't run into any problems accessing arrayfields directly in your string.

But that should do it now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#sortedtable").tablesorter({ sortlist: [0,0] });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if (!$link = mysql_connect("database_server", "user_name", "password")) {
        echo "Cannot connect to db server";
    } elseif (!mysql_select_db("database_name")) {
        echo "Cannot select database";
    } else {
        $searchString = "";
        if(!empty($_POST['search_b'])){
            $searchString = "WHERE user_name LIKE '%{$_POST['search_b']}%'";
        }
        if (!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table $searchString")) {
            echo "Cannot parse query";
        } elseif (mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
            echo "No records found";
        } else {
            echo "<table id=\"sortedtable\" class=\"bordered\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
            echo "<thead>\n<tr>";
            echo "<th>Record ID</th>";
            echo "<th>First Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Birthday</th>";
            echo "<th>Department</th>";
            echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
                echo "<tr><td>{$row[person_id]}</td><td>{$row[person_name]}</td><td>{$row[person_surname]}</td><td>{$row[person_birthdate]}</td><td>{$row[person_department]}</td></tr>\n";
            }
            echo "</table><br />\n";
        }
    }
    ?>

    <form name="search_form" method="POST" action="js.php">
        <font face="Calibri"> </font>
        Search: <input type="text" name="search_b" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search for your term..."> </input>
    </form>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, the only problem with this is that the initial database wont appear? its solely relying on a search term to make the results appear. i want the database to appear upon entering the page (which my code does), however i want a optional search box as well which i see you have added

Comment: what is wrong with my code? only if search_b is not empty i restrict the resultset. else there is no restriction applied!

Comment: i just extended your original code so that if you input some string in your searchbox then some filterin will be applied and else the whole table is being shown

Comment: terribly sorry, im going blind haha. many thanks it works perfect